# Can I add more corrections to page proofs?

Tags: publications, publishers, proofreading, journal-workflow

After my paper was accepted, I was sent page proofs with few corrections to some words and some references. Is it possible to add something to this page proofs. I want to change wording of a line that they didn’t mention so it makes better sense is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically it should be fine.

In my own experience large publishers (Springer, BMC etc) have outsourced the proofing process or at least a separate division does it. After Editor has viewed your paper along with possible revisions made proposed by the reviewers, the paper is usually moved to the people doing the proofing. Theoretically, you could make any corrections possible, since the writers have no expertise in the subject. At least this is my experience. They just do the job according the journals policy and instructions. As so, I strongly believe you can make corrections outside the proposed ones. In some journal journals they also inquire for "any other corrections". Of course if you make revisions which have any influence on the scientific matter there might be issues after publication.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, this is usually fine, as long as your changes are fairly minor and localized.